# Gerar animação a partir de gráfico

Tags: matlab

Estou gerando um gráfico com o seguinte comando:

```
X = linspace(0, 1, n);
Y = linspace(0, 1, n);
surf(X,Y,B(:,:));
```

Mas como fazer para que ele gere uma animação do gráfico? Não sei nada de MATLAB...

Answer (score 2):

É relativamente simples gerar animações em Matlab, você precisa criar um `for` e a cada passo gerar a saída desejada, chame a função `getframe` imediatamente após a função responsável por gerar o gráfico, esta função funciona como um print screen na janela do gráfico, coloque cada frame em uma posição e por fim chame a função `movie` para executar os frames capturados, as informações que você passou até o momento não são suficientes para entender qual é a saída esperada do seu algoritmo, ou seja você espera que ocorra movimento em seus vetores linearmente criados`(X,Y)` ou que estes se mantenham fixos e que ocorra apenas a animação em `B`, você precisa definir isso, um pseudo exemplo dos passos explicados acima:

```
for j = 1:50
     %A cada passo um surf diferente deve ser gerado de acordo com a sua necessidade 
     surf(X,Y,B(:,:));
     %captura os frames
     anima(j) = getframe;
end
%executa a animação no matlab
movie(anima,50)
```

Rode este exemplo para se familiarizar e veja o resultado:

```
Z = peaks;
figure('Renderer','zbuffer');
for j = 1:20
    surf(sin(2*pi*j/20)*Z,Z)
    F(j) = getframe;
end
movie(F,20)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, bom meu código está gerando essa onda:
![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/pFCCPa9.jpg)
eu queria a animação que pudesse ver o avanço dessa onda, porém não consegui com seu exemplo.

Comment: Foi como te disse sem ter o código completo não tem como te ajudar pois ninguém sabe se o avanço de sua onda está ocorrendo em X Y ou B

Comment: olhando rapidamente dá para notar que X e Y são estáticos você precisa mudar B em cada frame processado